# Entity Framework 4.0: Create an unmapped property in the model (currenty i get : error 11009 - Property is not mapped)?

Tags: entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-4

I know that i can enter/add new properties via code manually into partial classes but i wanted to use the model to add my new properties - reason being is that i can control a number of different attributes like NULL and things like that... and of course the code generations works great..

I added some foreign keys manually just on the model and they work great.

But everytime i add a SCALER PROPERTY i get an error in vs 2010 which says

Error   2538    Error 11009: Property 'testprop' is not mapped.

I can't believe i must map a custom property that i created to a column in the db.... is there no way to say "IGNORE" this property or treat as an unmapped property??

This way my code generation will create the required items BUT i don't get the error

Any help on this would be really helpful.

As i say i know i can edit things manually but wanted to update the model rather than edit a partial class....

I am sure i am missing something obvious?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363793/entity-framework-4-0-adding-scaler-property-gives-error-property-it-not-mapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that EF will on allow you to use the Model Designer to map to something that exists.  If you want to create a property that doesnt exist, you'll have to use the partial class.

Answer (score 3):

With *EntityFramework 5* you can use the `NotMappedAttribute` for unmapped properties. So, you can migrate to *EF5* or use partial classes on *EF4*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - you can use the NotMappedAttribute for unmapped properties...